# Good-Turing Smoothing Intuition

Tags: nlp

I'm working through the [Coursera NLP course by Jurafsky & Manning](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp), and the [lecture on Good-Turing smoothing](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/32) struck me odd.

The example given was:

> You are fishing (a scenario from Josh Goodman), and caught:
>   10 carp, 3 perch, 2 whitefish, 1 trout, 1 salmon, 1 eel = 18 fish
>   ...
>   How likely is it that the next species is new (i.e. catfish or bass)
>   Let's use our estimate of things-we-saw-once to estimate the new things.
>   3/18 (because N_1=3)

I get the intuition of using the count of uniquely seen items to estimate the number of unseen item types (N = 3), but the next steps seem counterintuitive.

Why is the denominator left unchanged instead of incremented by the estimate of unseen item types? I.e., I would expect the probabilities to become:

> Carp : 10 / 21
>   Perch : 3 / 21
>   Whitefish : 2 / 21
>   Trout : 1 / 21
>   Salmon : 1 / 21
>   Eel : 1 / 21
>   Something new : 3 / 21

It seems like the Good-Turing count penalizes seen items too much (trout, salmon, & eel are each taken down to 1/27); coupled with the need to adjust the formula for gaps in the counts (e.g., Perch & Carp would be zeroed out otherwise), it just feels like a bad hack.

Answer (score 3):

There are no *unseen* item types in the given data, by definition. 3 is the count of items seen *once*, and they are already included in the denominator 18. If the next item were *previously* unseen, it would become seen *once* when it appears. Since 3-of-18 examples were seen-once items, this is an estimate of the probability that the next item will be seen-once too on its first appearance.

It is certainly a heuristic. There is no way to know whether there are 0 or 1000 other types out there.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant unseen item types in the population being sampled; obviously there are none in the sample itself.